# Why can't I use variableHeightRows in three20?

Tags: ios, three20

In my `TTTableViewController` subclass, I'm setting `variableHeightRows = YES`. In my `TTTableViewCell` subclass, I've implemented

`+ (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)object`

The cell height is not varying at all, and Three20 doesn't even appear to be calling the rowHeightForObject method - I set a breakpoint inside it and during debugging it never hit my breakpoint. What am I doing wrong? Is there something else I need to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never encountered any problems with variableHeightRows, so just to throw out some random things to try:

- Are you sure the line executing `variableHeightRows = YES` is being called? Have you set a breakpoint there?
- Are you sure your subclass is actually the one populating the table (you've set it up properly in your data source).  Maybe try setting a breakpoint somewhere else in the subclass.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked your points with my code and without changing anything, it just started working.

Comment: Always a bittersweet result to a problem :)